# Is there a criterion that says at what point you can distinguish 2 partially overlapping Lorentzian peaks?

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, frequency-spectrum, power-spectral-density, frequency-domain

If you have 2 Lorentzian peaks that partially overlap and you have some frequency resolution df (your points in frequency space are separated by df) and both Lorentzian peaks have FWHM $\Gamma$ is there a critereon that says how large a frequency separation you need between the centres of the 2 Lorentzian peaks to distinguish them as 2 seperate peaks?

Comment: the answers are yes, but which answer depends on what you mean by distinguish.  You can use something like a Rayleigh criterion http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/Raylei.html.  You can also look at it as a statistical hypothesis test , where H0 is 1 peak as an example.  They don’t give the same answers

Comment: Do you gave an example you could link where they look at it as a statistical hypothesis test?